# Colorbox iFrame content not appearing in IE 8/9

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using ColorBox to call a few informational modals on-screen and given the client's requirements, the best way to do this is via iFrames (not my first choice but whatever). Everything is working peachy in Chrome, FF, etc. but the iFrame content is not working in any version of IE. The modal wrapper appears but nothing is inside. This is what I've done so far:

1. Changed the doctype to transitional and strict for IE. No dice.
2. Removed the "iframe: true" and replaced it with HTML "Hello". That worked fine and "Hello" appeared in the Colorbox modal.
3. I've removed all stylesheets from the header. No luck so it's not a CSS issue.
4. Just to be sure, I rolled back my JQuery library to 1.6.2 from 1.8.2. Nothing there, either.

Any help would be appreciated. This is aggravating.

Some code:

```
 $(function ()
{
    $(".modal-large").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:580, innerHeight:500});
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top-droptext"><a class="modal-large" href="modal/serviceproviderinfo.html">Update Password</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doctype issue. You need to add this to beginning of your colorbox caller page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: I tried that as I saw it was a common problem with ColorBox and IE. It's still not working.

But hey, maybe I'm implementing it wrong. Should I be using Strict for both the parent HTML page and the iFrame page? That's how I currently have it set up.

Comment: Well @Rocketpig, I just add this doctype into my caller page only, not the iframe page and it works on my end (IE8). Could you be more clear about not working here? It is the iframe cannot be loaded or the colorbox style that is broken?

Comment: The ColorBox modal is loading with the overlay and white "content" box. It opens and closes just fine in IE but the actual iFrame content is missing entirely. It's just a blank white box. In every other browser I've checked (Saf, Chrome, FF), everything works as it should. The ColorBox modal opens and the iFrame is displayed in the content div.

Comment: Have you tried to for example change your iframe to another URL (like http://wikipedia.com)? Just to make sure that it is not cache problem on browser maybe.

Comment: Oh man, you're awesome. That worked. I thought I had tried that already but it turns out I had only added an iFrame to the parent HTML to make sure it wasn't a general iFrame problem. I can get external links to display in IE. Now I need to figure out why my internal links aren't working.